# can not create a bootable USB in Windows 10 - access denied

Tags: windows-10

I can manipulate my USB flash memory with `diskpart` utility of Windows (I have full access to it) but when I want to create a bootable usb by using Win32 Disk Imager or rufus, both of them fails with an access denied error.

how can I fix this?

what I have tried with no success :

- clean the USB disk by `diskpart`.

Comment: It's better to use a third-party such as Rufus (here: https://rufus.ie/) or UnetBootIn (here: https://unetbootin.github.io/) to do that, because they're more efficient. When you do copy your Windows ISO onto the USB stick, make sure to choose the proper format between GPT and MBR, depending on the PC you're going to execute it on. EDIT: I hadn't noticed you had tried Rufus already. My apologies. Have you tried to run it as administrator (via right-click on the executable, then "run as administrator")?

Comment: yes. I ran it as Administrator, does not fix.

Comment: Have you tried Unetbootin? Also run it as admin, though I think it does that natively. Have you tried a different USB port each time?

Answer (score 5):

For me, it was Windows 10's **Ransomware Protection**, that I enabled at some point in the past.

It is supposed to prevent encryption of personal files (mostly to extort money), so it seems to prevent low-level access to drives.

To check and disable it in Windows 10, go to the Windows Settings (The cog wheel in the Start Menu), then to "Updates and Security", "Windows Security" (on the left), "Virus protection". Then at the bottom, there is "Ransomware protection". Click on it, then turn off "Controlled folder access". (This of course leaves your files vulnerable, should there be undetected Ransomware on your machine, but you have a backup anyway, don't you?)

Comment: There's also an option in `Windows Security` -> `Virus & threat protection` to "Add an allowed app". Add Rufus here. Given Rufus doesn't seem to have an installer, I manually set up a `C:\Program Files\Rufus` directory, put Rufus there, added my own shortcut to the start menu, and then created a Rufus exception to this (more stable) location. Rufus then 'burned' my ISO to USB.

Answer (score 3):

From what I think, this solution is not specific to the above problem. However, it relates to a similar scenario; one that I ,in fact, faced myself.

Rufus was being denied access to all USB flash drives that I tried(about 4), and I tried a lot of solutions(including using "diskpart") but that didn't work.

***To solve my particular problem all I had to do was turn off ESET Antivirus' device control.***

Comment: _ESET Anti Virus, if device control is enabled_ is mentioned word for word in the list of incompatible software I linked to in my answer. If you found that software mentioned in that list was the one that created an issue, you may want to upvote the existing answer, as it did provide you with the solution you were after.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered a similar problem while installing ParrotOs. However, things worked out after using the **[default Rufus](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/releases/download/v3.13/rufus-3.13.exe)** rather than the [portable version](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/releases/download/v3.13/rufus-3.13p.exe). The portable version causes such issues sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

In its FAQ, Rufus provides a **non-exhaustive** [list of software that can prevent access](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/wiki/FAQ#Incompatible_Software) (mostly security solutions), so you may want to check if you're not using one of these.

The problem is that some security solutions consider that USB Flash Drive access to reformat or change partition data is the sign of a malware infection, and make no provision for legitimate access such as the one from Win32 disk imager or Rufus (they may whitelist `diskpart` so that it won't produce an error, but that's about it).

Alternatively, some poorly designed software appear to keep a handle to removable drives (basically they are telling the OS: *"Please keep that drive open for me, I may need it"*), instead of just reopening the drive when actually required, which may also result in `Access Denied`.

If you are seeing consistent `Access Denied` issues, then you need to try to identify what software you have installed is the one that may be preventing access.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue, although for the very first time. Running using Compatibility settings applied worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Like others said, something can block access to drives, to verify that **run Windows in Safe Mode**.
I had similar problem with Rufus 3.14, tryied portable and nonportable version, compatibility modes and closing almost all processes but it didn't help, the one that solve it was Safe Mode.

If you don't do this all the time it could be the trick.

[How to boot Windows 10 in safe mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/start-your-pc-in-safe-mode-in-windows-10-92c27cff-db89-8644-1ce4-b3e5e56fe234)

Answer (score 0):

For me this issue fixed by turn off the windows defender or real time protection
[steps](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/turn-off-defender-antivirus-protection-in-windows-security-99e6004f-c54c-8509-773c-a4d776b77960).

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Please don’t post link only answers a the linked site might change, rendering your answer useless. Instead quote the most important parts and provide the link for reference only.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1160031)

Comment: Ok, sure. I'll post next time properly